# ProcessUserAuthorization is always null

Tags: openid, yahoo-oauth

I am trying to use the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms, but the line AuthorizedTokenResponse accessToken = Global.YahooWebConsumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(authResponse); keeps returning null. I am trying to use this project as is and the only change I made was change private const string YahooOPIdentifier = "yahoo.com"; to private const string YahooOPIdentifier = "me.yahoo.com";. I have added all my own tokens and secrets though.

The project is on: http://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-demo-dotnet

Thanks!

Comment: did you run the project in its completely unmodified form *first*, to see if that even works?

Comment: Yes and it fails first on no OpenID endpoint, which is because of the YahooOPIdentifier. Then it fails on ProcessUserAuthorization.